# Why can I not get a one dimensional array of a column as easy as a row?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, syntax

### Background

This is a 2d array.-

`String[][] names = { {"Sam", "Smith"}, {"Robert", "Delgro"}, {"James", "Gosling"}, };`

I can access the rows by calling this:
`names[n]`
Where n is any integer between the bounds and in this case **0<=`n`<=names.length-1**.
*Likewise*
I can call this
`String [] rowOne = names[0];`

---

### Inquiry

The question now remains,instead of rows, is there a way to access a *specific* column in the same way a *specific* row is accessed.

---

### Feedback

I would like feedback on this suggestion.
In the particular case of accessing a column in a **2d array**,`names[][x]`would be the declaration to call a specific column,where **0<=`x`<=names[0].length-1**.

`String[] columnOne = names[][0]`

This would mean that `names.length` would be *equivalent* to calling `names[][x].length`

This could also work for arrays **greater** than a *2d array*.

`String[][][]names = { {{"Sam", "Smith"}, {"Robert", "Delgro"}}, {{"James", "Gosling"}}};`

Just add extra square brackets.

*For example* In a 3d array, to access an **aisle**, which is what I will refer to the **3rd dimension**.
`names[][][z]`, where **0<=`z`<= names[0][1].length-1**

One dimensional arrays from multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Your suggested syntax is entirely sensible.  In fact, some other languages (APL, for instance) _do_ offer something comparable.  Just not Java.

Answer (score 0):

> ...is there a way to access a specific column in the same way a specific row is accessed.

No; Java's multidimensional arrays are essentially arrays that contain references to other arrays are not contiguous in memory. Java also allows arrays to be jagged. Let's say you have the following multidimensional array:

```
int[][] array = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5},
    {6}
};
```

By calling `array[][2]`, what would you expect to receive?  What about `array[][3]`?

To be able to get an array of columns, you would need to first transpose the multidimensional array.

Comment: Using my syntax suggestion, `array[][2] = {3};` but `array[][3]` would not exist since arrays start at index 0. I do agree that the arrays would have to transpose. Interesting note is that with current syntax ‘array[2] = {6};` is like `array[2][0] = 6;` in regards to elements. Likewise, with the suggested syntax, `array[][2] = {3};` is like `array[0][2] = 3`;.

Comment: @Paul However if the arrays at row index 0 and 1 were swapped then your proposed syntax, `array[][2]` would yield the same result, yet you have lost the index, so the result would have to also include `null`, but you can't for an array of primitives.